# WPF DataGrid Columns Duplication

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` binded to a List and when i start program everything is loaded `DataGrid` shows all content of the list but duplicates columns twice like in a picture.
[DataGrid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bISsD.png)

This is my code of `DataGrid`. Can anyone help why is this happening?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="componenttable" Height="140" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Component, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="12,105,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Maker" Binding="{Binding Maker}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Width="600" Binding="{Binding Notes}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.changeCommand, ElementName=componenttable}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Id}" >Change</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.deleteComponentCommand, ElementName=componenttable}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Id}">Delete</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: And only copy DataGridTextColumn and not Buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` to your DataGrid tag.